# How to include Draper Decorators in Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator, draper

I'd like to see the output of some of my Draper Decorators in Rails console (https://github.com/drapergem/draper and http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper). To do so, I was looking for a way to include a decorator and its methods similar to as we would an application helper:

```
 include ActionView::ApplicationHelper
```

A draper decorator inherits from an ApplicationDecorator, which inherits from Draper::Base

```
 class ApplicationDecorator < Draper::Base
 end

 class MaterialDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
    decorates :material
    #methods to decorate your material..
 end
```

I've tried `include Draper::Base::MaterialDecorator`, `include ApplicationDecorator::MaterialDecorator`, and some other similar variations with no luck.

How can I include a decorator such as the Material Decorator above in rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out (unless someone can show otherwise) that this isn't the way you test draper decorator output in rails console..

Instead, you just do:

```
 material = Material.first
 material = MaterialDecorator.decorate(material)
 material.some_decorator_method
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `app/decorators` to the Rails autoload path:

in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/decorators')
```

then, the decorator classes under that path should automatically be loaded, even in the `rails console`.  Example:

```
Material.first.decorate.some_decorator_method # => "good stuff"
```