# How do I create migrations for model attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm having difficulty with bulding attributes within my model. I keep seeing this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition:0x00007f9d9ad9df98>
```

I need attributes that look like this:

```
#group.rb

class Spree::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end

#user_decorator.rb
Spree::User.class_eval do
  belongs_to :group, class_name: "Spree::Group"
end
```

For group.rb I ran

```
rails g model Spree::Group
```

and I got:

```
class Spree::Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

I'm confused on how to add 'has_many :users' without actually going into the 
model and inputting it there.

For the user_decorator I'm not sure what that migration would look like. Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

You could call:

```
rails g model group user:references
```

which will generates an user_id column in the groups table and will modify the group.rb model to add a belongs_to :user relatonship. Please note, you must to put manually the has_many :groups or  has_one :group relationship to the user.rb model.

If you already have the model generated, you could create a migration with the following:

rails g migration AddUserToGroup user:belongs_to
which will generate:

```
class AddUserToGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :groups, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

the only difference with this approach is, the belongs_to :user relationship in the group.rb model won't be created automatically, so you must create it for your own.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Do you know how I would write a migration for the user_decorator?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557550/how-to-include-draper-decorators-in-rails-console